# Bootstrap Modal Confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I've got a table that displays user details per row along with a Remove button that launches a Bootstrap modal confirmation dialog box.

My goal is to have the confirmation button trigger an event which will delete that particular user.

How would I pass jsmith22 from the table row into my Javascript function?

**HTML Table**

```
<tr>
    <td>jsmith22</td>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>555-555-5555</td>
    <td>test@gmail.com</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block roster-button active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeUser">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

**Modal dialog**

```
<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="removeUser"
role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Remove Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you wish to remove this user?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-button" type="submit">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end modal-content -->
    </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- end modal -->
```

**Javascript**

```
// Remove button event trigger
$('#remove-button').click(function() {
        $.post('/API/removeUser', {} );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can do it with [Bootstrap Modal event listener](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Add data attribute `data-id` to modal trigger button

```
<td><button type="button" data-id="jsmith22" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeUser" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block roster-button active">Remove</button></td>
```

Add input `type="hidden"` to modal and pass the `id` value  to modal hidden input when shown

Hidden Input

```
<input type="hidden" id="RowId" value="">
```

Modal event `show` script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#removeUser').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $('#RowId').val(id);
     });
});
```

Now with `click` event

```
$('#remove-button').click(function() {
        var delid = $('#RowId').val();
        //Do what ever you like to do
        $.post('/API/removeUser', {} );
});
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hw0yb4gn/)

---

**Alternate Solution**

You can skip the `hidden` input and create a global variable

Modal trigger button with data attribute `data-id` to modal trigger button

```
<td><button type="button" data-id="jsmith22" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeUser" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block roster-button active">Remove</button></td>
```

Modal Event, Click function with Global variable script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var delid = ''; //global variable
  $('#removeUser').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    delid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); //fetch value of `data-id` attribute load it to global variable
    alert(delid);
  });

  $('#remove-button').click(function() {
    alert(delid); //Use the global variable here to del the record
    //Do what ever you like to do
    //$.post('/API/removeUser', {} );
  });
});
```

[Alternate Solution Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hw0yb4gn/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the first `td` of the button's row with getting this:

```
var person = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html()
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7j4bmgbv/